# Elasticsearch "_index" field optimizations

Tags: elasticsearch

I tried to do some queries to alias with multiple indices in Kibana with profiler and it seems that when you make high-level `filter` on `_index` field - it runs some really fast `MatchNoDocQuery` queries on all indices except the needed one.

E.g.: let's say we have two indices: `test.book` and `test.film`. We have an alias `test` with pattern `test.*`. Also each index has `product_type` field which may be "book" or "film".

It seems that this query:

```json
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "_index": ["test.film"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Is much faster than this query:

```json
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "product_type": ["film"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Are there any optimizations when running `filter` on "_index" field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query is faster because the query knows how to go through all the segments of the `test.film` index only and not check the segments of the `test.book` index. Whereas in the second, the query has no idea that there are multiple indexes and it will have to go through all the shards.

Say both indexes have 10 segments, which means 20 segments in total when running the query of the alias. The first query will only go through 10 segments, whereas the second will have to go through the 20 segments in order to figure out the documents that satisfy the condition.

Comment: I understand it but i tried to do some queries in Kibana with profiler to alias with multiple indices and it seems that when you make `filter` on `_index` - it runs some really fast `MatchNoDocQuery` queries on all indices except the needed one. And i can't google anything about it. So i wonder if there is some not obvious logic.

Comment: Of course `filter` will reduce the document set on which the query has to run, so it will be faster for sure, `post_filter` is for a totally different use case

Comment: I tried to make a question more clear. Sorry for inconvenient reference.

Comment: Thanks, makes much more sense now, I've updated my answer